# Closing a Panel from iframe in Firefox Add-ons

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm creating a Firefox extension with addons SDK which open an iframe with information from the current page. After some actions to iframe I would need to close the Panel object but I don't know how to pipe this message. Any ideas? In Chrome I was able to just close the window and extension would close.

The code: https://github.com/kippt/kippt-firefox/blob/master/lib/main.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll have to create a content script, which registers a listener to be called when you want to close the panel. The content script should communicate with the addon via `self.port.emit('your-event-name')`, and the add-on code should listen for the notification via `panel.port.on('your-event-name')` to close the panel:

```
        var kipptPanel = require("panel").Panel({
            width:400,
            height:245,
            // The contentURL should do this to close the panel:
            // <button id="close-button">self.port.emit('close', null)</button>
            contentURL : "http://localhost:8000/test-panel.html",
            contentScript: "document.getElementById('close-button').addEventListener('click', function() {" +
                           "  console.log('zz');self.port.emit('close', null);" +
                           "});"
        });
        kipptPanel.port.on("close", function (text) {
          console.log(text);
          kipptPanel.destroy();
        });
        kipptPanel.show();
```

Here's a [modified version of your code in the add-on builder](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1045025/latest/).

This is described at the [SDK's panel documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/addon-kit/docs/panel.html).

I realize it's too complicated, you might want to ask in the jetpack group if making `window.close()` close the panel has been considered.

Comment: I'm not sure closing a panel when a tab closes would make any sense as a general feature. The panel is part of the browser chrome, and *not* attached to any given tab.

Comment: @canuckistani: the way I parsed that sentence in the question was: when you call `window.close()` in the document opened in the panel, the panel will close (in Chrome). It makes sense to me.

Comment: Awesome, this was the thing I was looking for. Thanks so much!

Comment: @jorde: glad to help. Somehow I forgot to link the SDK documentation, where all this is explained in detail. See the new link in the updated answer.